# Telegram - Node api. How do I get the userID of the user to whom im replying to when I trigger a specific regex match?

Tags: javascript, node.js, telegram, node-telegram-bot-api

Imagine that theres one user message in the chat, and I, as another user, do the following

Answer to his text with: /tip 50

I basically want to somehow receive , the user to whom I have answered to, (his id) , and the second parameter.
I cant seem how to do so since msg doesnt contain the id of the user who you answered to

I dont really have anything right now, this is my code

```
    `bot.onText(/\/tip/,(msg,res) => {
    var tg_chat_id = msg.chat.id
    var tg_ser_id = msg.from.id
    console.log(res)
    console.log(msg)
    // bot.onReplyToMessage(msg.chat.id, msg.from.id)

})`
```

I was thinking about logging the msg and finding there the userID to whom I answered. But I cant see it. Maybe I can use bot.onReplyToMessage to achieve it, but I dont understand it.

Comment: mouchin777, could you please mark the answer as accepted if it helped you. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

To capture the passed parameter within the [`onText`](https://github.com/yagop/node-telegram-bot-api/blob/release/doc/api.md#TelegramBot+onText) method, you need to compose your regexp properly and pass the match to the callback function. To reply to a specific message, pass the `reply_to_message_id` option to the [`sendMessage`](https://github.com/yagop/node-telegram-bot-api/blob/release/doc/api.md#TelegramBot+onText) method, like this:

```js
bot.onText(/\/tip (.+)/, (msg, match) => {
    let chatId = msg.chat.id;
    let messageId = msg.message_id;
    let tipValue = match[1];
    bot.sendMessage(chatId, `You tipped with value: ${tipValue}`, {
        reply_to_message_id: messageId
    });
});
```

This will result in the following bot's reply:

[image]